# Branch depending on uniform only

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I know that branches in GPU programs (shaders, CUDA, CL, ...) behave different (performance-wise) than branches in CPU programs. Typically, instances of a shader are grouped and instances from the same group compute the same path. If in one group there is an instance which wants to take one path and another instance wants to take another path, both paths are evaluated and this might drop the performance if this situation happens often.

But what if ***all instances*** of the shader program take the ***same path***? I.e. what if the branch is only influenced by a single boolean uniform value? In particular compared to branchless (i.e. when eliminating the branch during compile time of the shader program; keeping two shader program objects in the host program and swapping them when needed).

```
uniform bool dosomething = false;

...
    if (dosomething) {
        expensiveStuff();
    }
...
```

Above I spoke of a single branch; but what if the branch is even in a loop? Can it be "detected" that it's always taking the same path for (a) all instances of the shader + (b) all loop iterations?

Consider something like ray marching, where some computationally expensive detail is triggered / influenced by a uniform.

```
...
    for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += step) { 
        foo();
        if (dosomething) {
            expensiveStuff();
        }
    }
...
```

Is it worth transforming the code into something like this (if possible)?

```
...
    if (dosomething) {
        for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += step) { 
            foo();
            expensiveStuff();
        }
    } else {
        for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += step) { 
            foo();
        }
    }
...
```

I'm targeting mainly NVIDIA and AMD GPUs (GL version >= 4.0), but am interested in a more "general" answer, i.e. based on experience in professional shader programming, since I don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it worth transforming the code into something like this (if possible)?

Yes.

While a GLSL compiler *can* do optimizations like that there's no spec-guarantee that it *will*.

Comment: I already guessed that the spec won't say anything about that. But I hoped that someone can say what *typical* implementations do (i.e. NVIDIA, AMD).

Comment: So I guess the (now outer) branch might still be not optimized out, but it would not really hurt? (I still imagine the worst case that each instance runs the two possible paths at the outer branch.)

Comment: The worst case you can have with branches (and some other thinngs like gradients) in shaders _non-uniform control flow_. You are interested in uniform control flow, which typically is not as bad on those platforms. However, I would try to avoid branches in general as much as possible. Especially with your `uniform bool` case it might be more efficient to (pre)generate shaders for the specific cases (maybe by inserting a `const bool=...` into the source code). Keeping a few of these shader variants around is not that resource consuming.